# String split based on pattern and size

Tags: ruby, string

I want to split a query string like:

```
"(first_name:zach AND last_name:woods) OR (first_name:thomas AND last_name:middleditch) OR (first_name:martin AND last_name:starr) OR "...
```

into substrings, each not greater than 5000 characters, and I want to split on the pattern `" OR "`.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you constructing this query ? It would be better to have this constraints while generating the query itself.

Comment: Suppose your string were `"(monkey AND gorilla) OR (owl AND hen) OR (rat AND mouse)"`.  If the limit were 35 rather than 5000, what object do you wish returned? For example, would that be `["(monkey AND gorilla)" , "(owl AND hen) OR (rat AND mouse)"]`, where `"(monkey AND gorilla)".size #=>  20`,  `"(monkey AND gorilla) OR (owl AND hen)".size #=> `37` and `"(owl AND hen) OR (rat AND mouse)".size #=> 32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is just like the example, you can just split by `OR`, then loop through the substrings to join them together until it reaches 5000 characters.

```
original_query = "(first_name:zach AND last_name:woods) OR ..."
split_arr = original_query.split(/(?<=OR)/) # Split but keeps delimiter OR
result = []
pattern = ""
split_arr.each do |query|
  if (pattern.length + query.length) > 5000 # If reached limit
    result.push(pattern)                    # Store the current pattern
    pattern = query                         # Start new substring   
  else                                      # Else
    pattern = pattern + " " + query         # Just add more query to current pattern
  end
end

result.push(pattern) if pattern.length > 0  # Check for the final case

puts result
```

Then, you will get the array `result` with substrings that are less than 5000 characters. However, given your string is an SQL query (maybe), whether the substrings are correct syntactically or not depends on your original query.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have these query constraints while building the query itself.

If you still want to work with this approach, one way would be to `scan` the conditions and concatenate them based on the size you preferred.

```
# Scan all matching conditions
conditions = str.scan(/first_name:[a-z]+ AND last_name:[a-z]+/)

# Final queries array
result = []

# Iterate over the conditions array as batch collection and build query
# Considering average size of each one as 35, batching group of 140 items
conditions.in_groups_of(140) { |group| group.reduce { |x, y| result << (x + (y.nil? ? '' : ' OR '+ y)) } }
```

The result array would have the queries split by size.